# Sum of a constant over a domain

Tags: summation

After some research, I cannot find a solution to this very basic question:

> What is the sum of a constant over a domain (of a variable X):
> $$\sum_{X \in \{0,1\}} 1 = ??$$

I would say that the result is $2$ but I am not sure.

Thanks by advance

Aymeric

Comment: You are summing over the reals?  But any sum of uncountably many positive terms diverges.  In this case, even the harmonic sum $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, I am summing over X belonging to the domain {0,1}

Comment: Sorry, do you just mean that the sum is over the two points $0$ and $1$?  In that case, the answer is certainly $2$.  I thought you meant that you were summing over the entire interval from $0$ to $1$.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|\{0, 1\}| = 2$ then the sum in the question equals 2. It is similar to $\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$.